# converting RELAX NG to XSD with trang while keeping external namespace elements (for use with JAXB)

Tags: xsd, namespaces, jaxb, relaxng

I am using [`trang`](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) to convert a RELAX NG .rng file to an XML Schema .xsd file for use with JAXB. Is there a way to put  attributes/elements in the .rng file and have them show up in the .xsd file? I have an external .xjb file that I use for JAXB settings, but there are some JAXB settings that are very closely coupled to the schema itself and it seems like it makes more sense to (somehow) put them in the .rng file rather than the .xjb file.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is that what you're doing now is the best way and you should keep your JAXB customizations separate from your RELAX NG schema.  JAXB customizations in an XML Schema are ugly at best, distracting and confusing at worse.  With RELAX NG, there's much less of a mapping and my guess is that you'll still  need to put some of the customizations in a separate JAXB customization file, which means that your customizations will be in two different files.